# Maverics VPN to Windows 2008 SSTP with Certificate (PPTP)

Tags: macos, vpn, ssl, pptp

I'm unable to connect to a Windows VPN using my macbook air 2013.
The VPN Settings given to me are,

1. Server URL
2. Username & Password
3. SSL Ceritificate
4. VPN Type - SSTP

I have added image on how to configure VPN connection on Windows. Please help on how to configure this VPN on Mac OS X Maverics.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's support article, [OS X: Set up a connection to a virtual private network](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14079), walks through the steps:

> 1. Choose **Apple menu > System Preferences**, then click **Network**.
> 2. Click **Add (+)** at the bottom of the network connection services list, then choose **VPN** from the Interface pop-up menu.
> 3. Choose what kind of VPN connection you want to set up from the VPN Type pop-up menu, depending on the network you are connecting to, and
>      give the VPN service a name.
> 4. Enter the server address and the account name for the VPN connection.
> 5. Click **Authentication Settings**, then enter the user authentication information you were given by the network administrator.
> 6. After entering the user authentication information, click **OK**, then click **Connect**.

Below is a screen shot showing the PPTP VPN settings. **Authentication Settings…** contains the option for applying your certificate.

[image: VPN with PPTP asking for a certificate]

Comment: This settings does not provide a place to add username & password. Also, I can't seem to locate the certificate in the given list when I click "Select".

Comment: Add the certificate to your keychain using the Keychain Access application. Then try with the Account Name & Password approach.